# Unusual output format required in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table in the format;

```
Name   Date         Value
ABC    1/21/2015    52
ABC    1/22/2015    12
ABC    1/23/2015    32
DEF    1/21/2015    78
DEF    1/22/2015    53
etc...
```

For compatibility with a legacy program I need to format a text file as follows:

```
ABC
1/21/2015,52
1/22/2015,12
1/23/2015,32
DEF
1/21/2015,78
1/22/2015,53
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I would build a console program if possible - parse the input and insert into db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to create header rows for the result set using a `UNION` and then sort such that they appear at the top of each `Name` group.  You can do this using a computed column which identifies these generated rows as being headers.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.Header = 1
       THEN t.Name
       ELSE CONCAT(t.Date, ',', t.Value)
       END
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Name, NULL AS Date, NULL AS Value, 1 AS Header
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, Date, Value, 0 AS Header
    FROM yourTable
) t
ORDER BY t.Name, t.Header DESC, t.Date
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, OP is trying to read the input from that format but not generate the output as you suggested, isn't it?

Comment: @ydooow Huh?  The OP states that it has a table with a certain format and wants to do a `SELECT`.  Why did you downvote this?

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for this solution.  It's a nice, compact way of adding the headers as well as the relevant data without using an overly-complicated query or multi-part solution.  Could just copy-paste if they wanted from the results into NP++ or just directly save the output as a text file.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a hack, but the result is what you need:

The trick is, to use an intermediate XML in this form:

```
<x>ABC</x>
<x>2015.01.21,52</x>
<x>2015.01.22,12</x>
<x>2015.01.23,32</x>
<x>DEF</x>
<x>2015.01.21,78</x>
<x>2015.01.22,53</x>
```

Then it is easy to read each "node":

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),Date DATE,Value INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('ABC','1/21/2015',52)
,('ABC','1/22/2015',12)
,('ABC','1/23/2015',32)
,('DEF','1/21/2015',78)
,('DEF','1/22/2015',53);

WITH DistinctNames AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT One.Line.value('.','varchar(100)') AS OneLine
FROM
(
SELECT
(
SELECT Name AS [x]
        ,(
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t.Date,102) + ',' + CAST(t.Value AS VARCHAR(100))
        FROM @tbl AS t
        WHERE t.Name=DistinctNames.Name
        FOR XML PATH('x'),TYPE
        )
FROM DistinctNames
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
)
) AS tbl(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/x') AS One(Line)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this for me would be to use the query.

```
SELECT Name, Date, Value 
FROM Table
ORDER BY Name ASC, Date ASC
```

And then use a short PHP script that every time that gets a new Name, echoes it and dumps all lines until a new Name is found.

```
<?php
// SQL
$name = "";
foreach ($response as &$line) {
    if ($name != $line['Name']) {
        $line['Name'] = $name;
        echo $name . "<br />";
    }
    echo $line['Date'] . "," . $line['Value'] . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

And save it to a text file.

*Note: You could use a "million" different languages. I just wrote in PHP because for me it would be the most accessible. My idea would be the same for others.*